# Почему IDE требует С++ компилятор для С кода?

Tags: c, ide, gcc, c++

> Code::Blocks 8.02
> Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (x86_64)

Пишу Сишный код. Компилятор ругается, что нет g++, и просит установить. Установил. Заработало. Теперь вопрос, в чем отличие скомпилированного кода Си в gcc от кода Си в g++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Почему IDE требует С++ компилятор для С кода?

Все очень просто. В качестве линкера (компоновщика связей) используется g++:

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -c /home/gaal/TEST/TEST/main.c -o obj/Release/main.o
g++ -o bin/Release/TEST obj/Release/main.o -s
```

> Теперь вопрос, в чем отличие скомпилированного кода Си в gcc от кода Си в g++?

См. комментарии к [предыдущему ответу](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/7411/208074).
Если компилятор — gcc, а линкер — g++, то просто будут добавлены зависимости от библиотек C++.
Если компилятор и линкер — g++ с ключами для C-кода, то опять же будут определенные библиотеки. Но по идее код будет «Сишным».

Comment: Поставил в настройках линкер gcc, удалил с компа g++ и стало компилировать Си код без потребности в g++.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

В бинарник будет зашит рантайм C++, возможно, добавятся какие-нибудь дополнительные секции.

Будут другие библиотечные зависимости:

`C`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff6ab46000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0eb1149000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0eb14f4000)
```

`C++`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff12fff000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe1cab00000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe1ca87d000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe1ca666000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe1ca2e3000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe1cae2e000)
```

Вот такой код:

```
int main(){}
```

скомпилированный (`gcc`, `g++`) и дизассемблированный отличался только строками:

```
// в начале main
.cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
...
// при выходе из main
movl    $0, %eax
```

В варианте C++ обе были добавлены. Первая строка - видимо, какие-то метаданные, а вот вторую объяснить не могу, но в общем ничего существенного. Зачем-то обнуляется регистр `eax`.

Comment: Вообще-то G++ умеет собирать C-код как C-код:
<pre>gaal@linux-lybs:~> g++ -x c 1.c
gaal@linux-lybs:~> ldd ./a.out
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7874000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7707000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb78ac000)</pre>

Comment: А это gcc родной:
<pre>gaal@linux-lybs:~> gcc 1.c
gaal@linux-lybs:~> ldd ./a.out
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb757b000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7702000)</pre>

Comment: <pre>movl $0, %eax</pre>
А это очень просто - return 0. Т.к. возвращаемое значение ДОЛЖНО быть. По умолчанию - 0.

Comment: Ага но в варианте Си этого `movl $0` нету.

Comment: Может быть. А теперь измените тело main на {return 0;}, как того требует стандарт и посмотрите, что будет.

Comment: Да, теперь есть. Но всё равно странно. Почему g++ по умолчанию добавляет возвращение 0, а gcc нет.

Comment: Это нормальное явление. Дело в том, что C - намного менее строгий язык. Если ничего специально не включать, то можно передавать в функции чёрт знает какие параметры, можно не возвращать ничего из функции с явно указанным возвращаемым типом.. в общем, слабый контроль за типиами.